# "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required" when I try to install gnuplot

Tags: software-installation

I want to install `gnuplot` on Ubuntu 12.04. However, it always fails with the following log:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnuplot is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-zh-hans
   language-pack-kde-en-base kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-zhcn
   language-pack-zh-hans-base firefox-locale-zh-hans
   language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely nothing. The output tells you that `gnuplot is already the newest version`.

Comment: Then how to start it, I didn't get it in the search-bar.

Comment: @Ub-lx did you try running `gnuplot` through either alt+f2, or from the terminal?

Comment: @Ub-lx as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot) says, it is a command line tool, so try using terminal. You might start with one of [many](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~vrable/gnuplot/using-gnuplot.html) [tutorials](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html) [available](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/comput/gnuplot.html).

Comment: @ Thomas W, from terminal.

Comment: @Ub-lx do you mean that if you enter `gnuplot` in terminal, you get some sort of error, or nothing happens? It should give you the gnuplot prompt, different than standard `bash` prompt (`gnuplot>` in my 12.04).

Comment: When I write gnuplot then I see: 
G N U P L O T
 Version 4.4 patchlevel 3
 last modified March 2011
 System: Linux 3.2.0-48-generic-pae

 Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2010
 Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

 gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
 faq, bugs, etc:   type "help seeking-assistance"
 immediate help:   type "help"
 plot window:      hit 'h'

Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot>

Comment: @Ub-lx so there you go. It is a gnuplot prompt. You may enter gnuplot commands there. Or you may write commands to a file and then run `gnuplot < filename`. Do some tutorial to get a feeling how the app works and what you can do with it.

Answer (score 8):

Ub-lx

You could try this command for installing the GNU plot and work on it

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```

and using this pdf you can learn GNU plot: http://fig.if.usp.br/~lucmod/tips/gnuplotbook.pdf

Answer (score 1):

just issue

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```

which will default to using the QT backend since X11 is getting long in the tooth

Answer (score 0):

5.0.1 from source on 14.04:

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gnuplot login
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gnuplot co -P gnuplot
cd gnuplot
cvs update -r Release_5_0_1
sudo apt-get build-dep gnuplot
sudo apt-get install lua5.2
./prepare
./configure
time make
sudo make install
gnuplot --version
```

15.04 has the [gnuplot5-x11](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/gnuplot5-x11) package.

Answer (score 0):

GNUplot packages:

```
gnuplot-nox
gnuplot-qt
gnuplot-x11
```

To install, you can use

```
sudo apt install <selected-package>
```