# Gnuplot 4.6.4 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, octave

I tried to install Gnuplot-4.6.4 in Ubuntu 12.04 after following http://priyansmurarka.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/gnuplot-on-ubuntu-12-04/ but it gave following error after `sudo make`

> In file included from wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp:96:0:
>   wxterminal/wxt_gui.h:161:3: error: #error "wxt does not know if this
>   platform has to be mono- or multi-threaded" wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp: In
>   function ‘bool wxt_exec_event(int, int, int, int, int, wxWindowID)’:
>   wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp:3331:7: error: ‘wxt_sendevent_fd’ was not
>   declared in this scope wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp:3336:13: error:
>   ‘wxt_sendevent_fd’ was not declared in this scope
>   wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp: In function ‘void wxt_atexit()’:
>   wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp:3593:34: warning: ignoring return value of
>   ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’, declared with
>   attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
>   wxterminal/wxt_gui.cpp:3594:34: warning: ignoring return value of
>   ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’, declared with
>   attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

How to install it?

Comment: 14.04 build from source procedure: http://askubuntu.com/a/684136/52975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread solved the problem
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189523

It can be installed from this PPA https://launchpad.net/~gladky-anton/+archive/precise-backports