# Uninstall software if I don't know where I initially installed it

Tags: apt, update-alternatives

I'm sure this question has been answered, but I am unable to find it.  A few years back I installed gnuplot 4.4 and now I am wanting to update it to 4.6.  The problem is when I went to do

```
sudo apt-get remove gnuplot
```

it said that gnuplot was not installed.  So I then went looking for the folder in which I build it (since if I built it, it would not show up as being an apt able to be removed).  I could not find the folder to remove it, i.e.

```
make uninstall
```

My next thought was to get 4.6 from the software center and use update-alternatives, but it returned that there were no alternatives for gnuplot.  I'm assuming that it still can't see the first one?  Anyways, if I could get pointed in the right direction, that would be amazing.

Comment: Simply use `sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11` to install it. The full instructions can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/340579/how-to-install-gnuplot-in-ubuntu

Comment: If you installed gnuplot 4.4 from a compressed source code file like a .tar.gz or some such, you'll have to locate that software first, download it again, and then do a `sudo make uninstall`. Then you should be able to install 4.6.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix They really need to uninstall 4.4 first. And v5.0.5 is what your recommendation would install, not the 4.6 the user wants.

Comment: @heynnema The key point is it's not `gnuplot` but rather `gunplot-x11` according to the link. I didn't pick up on the fact they didn't want the current version. In that case we'd have to fine tune the answer to freeze the package.